# CSS: "width" and "height" for cells

Tags: css, cell, css-tables

I have this [page](http://www.tirengarfio.com/rs2/web/miembros).

```
login: maria@mail.com
password: m
```

I've gave a width to "td.select_edad label" but it doesnt work..

I know it's deprecated, so what is your advice?

Another question: why "height" (also deprecated) is working ok for the fields of the filter?

Comment: Just a guess...label isn't set to 'display: block'.

Comment: CSS width and CSS height are not deprecated, nor are width attributes for td cell. It looks like you set it to 15px and that's about the right size.

Comment: Hmm, I can't find "select_edad" in the source code of that page?!

Comment: i just wonder to know who have voted up for this question!? O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`label` is an inline element so `width` does not have any effect.

You can set the `label` to `display:block` and then it will work as you want.

**By the way**, `width` and `height` are definitely not deprecated in css. They are probably deprecated as inline attributes (if that´s the right word...) for tables.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is don't use tables to layout forms. Use a fieldset and divs as necessary. Have a look at the [WuFoo Form Gallery](http://wufoo.com/gallery/) for inspiration.

Comment: Here's a good overview of what's wrong with tables:
http://www.chromaticsites.com/blog/13-reasons-why-css-is-superior-to-tables-in-website-design/